# PHP make if shorter

Tags: php, if-statement

What is a true way to write like:

```
if ($variable == '(value1/value2/value3)' ) { }
```

It should work similar to:

```
if ($variable == 'value1' || $variable == 'value2' || $variable == 'value3') { }
```

Just want to make this code shorter (now I use `switch`).

Thanks.

Comment: I'd stick with `switch` myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($variable, array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'))) {}
```

If you do happen to have a group of values separated by, in your example, a `/`, just [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it and you'll have an array to plug into `in_array()`:

```
if (in_array($variable, explode('/', 'value1/value2/value3'))) {}
```

It might seem like you could just use [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead since it's a long string of values, but that's *not* how one would work with a delimited string of multiple values (use `explode()` instead, as above):

```
if (strpos('value1/value2/value3', $variable) !== false) {}
```

Comment: use `strpos` and get values like "value1/val" or "ue1"

Comment: @valya: exactly, which is why `strpos()` isn't the right way to do it even though it might seem to make sense at first :)

Comment: But wouldn't it be simple to use a regex? Like: `if(preg_match('/%$6^$%^-`jil9(*&(((&&(*&((&%%%88&value1*^*&^))&*!@#!value2%*^*^&*^*^*value3', '(value1/value2/value3)');` ? Sometimes you guys just don't think straight, if you ask me ;)

Comment: @karim79: ha, that made me chuckle :)

Answer (score 2):

Also shorter:

```
if (preg_match('#^(?:value1|value2|value3)$#', $variable) {
```

Not that it's necessarily the best way to do it.  The long way, using just if and || statements, is going to be simple to read even though it's lengthy, and will be the most efficient to run.

Comment: `value[1-3]` with the appropriate modifications to suit PHP's Regex would work also.

Comment: I thought it obvious that value1, value2 and value3 were just placeholders for the sake of example.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch ($variable)
{
    case "value1":
    case "value2":
    case "value3":
        ...
        break;
    default: // else
        ...
}
```